# I am trying to streamline or speed up the following query:

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table table_3 as     
select *
from table_1 
   join table_2 on tbl.1.C1 = tbl.2.C1
or tbl.1.C1 = tbl.2.C2 
or tbl.1.C1 = tbl.2.C3
or tbl.1.C1 = tbl.2.C4
or tbl.1.C1 = tbl.2.C5
or tbl.1.C1 = tbl.2.C6
```

There is a total of 10 columns in table 2 that I need to check.  Basically, I want to check table 2 for the table 1 value if table 2 column1 is Null or non-match look in table 2 column2 if null or non-match look in table 2 column3....

Comment: could you provide some context? Why do you want to do with that query?

Comment: I have a list of id #s in table_1 and those id #s can be contained in any of the 10 table_2 columns.  If they match I am need to pull a different id_# out of table_2.

Comment: Your syntax here makes no sense. Are you trying to create a view? Your syntax is trying to create a table as a select statement which doesn't work. And you query is confusing because you are sort of referencing aliases except those aliases don't exist and the format is not right either.

Comment: Normalize table_2 or unpivot the data.

Comment: create view.  I made the aliases for simplicity sake. table_1 shortened to tbl.1

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if I understand your query, by you can try it:

```
CREATE TABLE table_3 AS 
  SELECT COALESCE(B.c1, C.c2, D.c3, E.c4, F.c5, G.c6) 
  FROM   table_1 A 
         LEFT JOIN table_2 B 
                ON A.c1 = B.c1 
         LEFT JOIN table_2 C 
                ON A.c1 = C.c2 
         LEFT JOIN table_2 D 
                ON A.c1 = D.c3 
         LEFT JOIN table_2 E 
                ON A.c1 = E.c4 
         LEFT JOIN table_2 F 
                ON A.c1 = F.c5 
         LEFT JOIN table_2 G 
                ON A.c1 = G.c6
```

In this code first try find the value of table_2.c1, if it is null try the value of table_2.c2.....

Comment: I like this because it follows, "I want to check table 2 for the table 1 value if table 2 column1 is Null or non-match look in table 2 column2 if null or non-match look in table 2 column3...."

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here as to what you are trying to do because your post is not clear. I think you want to join when ANY of a list of columns in table2 match the value in table1. This is kind of a big sign that something is pretty off in your design but the query is easy enough. Something like this.

```
select *
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.C1 in (t2.C1, t2.C2, t2.C3, t2.C4, t2.C5)
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps normalize/unpivot the data then join?

```
select *
from table_1  t1
join (Select c1 as cNorm, differentID_# from table_2 UNION ALL 
      Select c2, differentID_# from table_2 UNION ALL 
      Select c3, differentID_# from table_2 UNION ALL 
      Select c4, differentID_# from table_2 UNION ALL
      Select c5, differentID_# from table_2 UNION ALL
      Select c6, differentID_# from table_2 UNION ALL
      Select c7, differentID_# from table_2 UNION ALL
      Select c8, differentID_# from table_2 UNION ALL
      Select c9, differentID_# from table_2 UNION ALL
      Select c10, differentID_# from table_2) t2
 on t1.c1 = t2.cNorm
```

This will match on any values and doesn't progress from c1-c10.

Comment: thanks.  talked to my DBA and they actually already had another unpivoted table made!

Answer (score 0):

`or` in a `join` statement can kill performance.  It is unclear what you really want to do, but the following might product a better optimization plan:

```
select *
from table_2 t2 join
     table_1 t1
     on t1.C1 = t2.C1
union all
select *
from table_2 t2 join
     table_1 t1
     on t1.c1 = t2.c2 and t1.c1 not in (t2.c1)
union all
select *
from table_2 t2 join
     table_1 t1
     on t1.c1 = t2.c3 and t1.c1 not in (t2.c1, t2.c2)
. . .
```